# Save a counter value across page refreshes

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'd like to add 1 to a value every 2.7 seconds; I'd *not* like it to reset every time I refresh the page

Is there a way to augment the following code to make this possible? I don't know anything about php, and very little JS, but I'd like to learn php, and I feel it could be a solution.

Here's the line with the counter.

```
<span id="counter" class="bladeometer" style="letter-spacing: 3px;">198567970</span>
```

Here's the code that works it.

```
var timer;


function startCount()
{
timer = setInterval(count,2700);
}
function count()
{
var el = document.getElementById('counter');
var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
el.innerHTML = currentNumber+1;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved purely with Javascript. It will be kept in sync after page refreshes, and it will even be the same for all users visiting the website.

```
var el = document.getElementById('counter');
//Set the date of when it starts to February 3rd, 2013. Javascript counts months from 0-11
var startTime = Math.floor(new Date(2013, 1, 3) / 1000);
var startNumber = 200000000;

var timer = setInterval(function() {
    var currentTime = Math.floor(new Date() / 1000);
    var secondsSinceStart = currentTime - startTime;

    el.innerHTML = Math.floor(startNumber + (secondsSinceStart / 2.7));
}, 2700);
```

The way it works is that it calculates how many seconds have gone by since the counter started, and divides that by 2.7 to see what the value of the counter should be. I use `Math.floor()` so that the number in the counter is a whole number.

What `Date.time()` does is get the number of milliseconds since the Epoch (you can read about it at 
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date) ). 
I divide it by 1000 to get the number of seconds since the Epoch then I floor it so that number is a whole number.

If you need any help understanding any part of it, feel free to ask.

Demo: http://codepen.io/skimberk1/pen/dbf41f6dae413a39bd05650ef8796319

Comment: I see this working on the demo, but not when I add it to my code. What step am I missing? I'd like to make it start at the value startTime is set to, or another approximation later. When you create new Date(), what is its initial value? And why is it divided by 1000?

Comment: It's all explained in my answer. new Date()`.getTime()` returns the time in milliseconds since the Unix epoch. Division by 1000 gets us from milliseconds to seconds.

Comment: I edited the answer to answer your questions. You should change the value of startNumber to change what number the counter starts at.

Comment: Okay, cool. How would I return the time in milliseconds since a time after the Unix epoch? Like say when the company opened for business and started creating their product every 2.7 seconds?

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` but why would you need milliseconds there? Both our answers give you seconds, which is what you need.

Comment: If you want to update the `startTime`, use `Math.floor(new Date() / 1000)` to get the number of seconds since the Epoch.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn'tve typed milliseconds. The company I'm doing this for makes lawnmower blades, and they expect to hit 200 mil. blades produced sometime this year. I assume I need to know the date they started producing (1950), and how many they've made so far. (Which I can ask them about.)

Comment: @user2658433 Take some time this year, assign 200M to that time, and from there calculate the start time.

Comment: If you tell me what date your company is expecting to hit 200M sales, I can update the code so it works for you.

Comment: (Thank you, math isn't my strong suit.)Lets say... December 3rd. Any old time.

Comment: Also, where does startNumber come into play?

Comment: I forgot to use startNumber. I updated the answer to fix that.

Comment: This has all been very helpful! 
If you've got time I have a few final questions. The time updates in the demo console, how do I make the script affect the the number between the span tags at the top of this page?

Comment: Here's a demo of what you're trying to do. It will reach 200M on December 3rd, 2013. http://codepen.io/skimberk1/pen/faa343f0eb691f147e40bd5d4d0ebcd1

Comment: Just replace the Javascript that you have with the Javascript from the demo. It should work without any changes.

Comment: If this answer helped you, I'd appreciate it if you upvoted it and selected it as your accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the help, but my counter's not moving. :(

Comment: That's weird. Could you send a url to the page so I can try to figure out what's wrong? If you pasted everything correctly it should work.

Comment: [Here's the page with the un-updated counter and all the files.](http://sems-usa.com/Duramatic/index) Excuse the design choices.

Comment: Copy and paste the code from here: http://pastebin.com/tn7iQmnv The problem was that it was being called before the DOM was loaded. I just put the code in the startCount function, as it's called once the `body` fully loads.

Comment: Again, if this answer helped you please upvote this answer and accept it by clicking the check at the top left of the answer.

Comment: The counter works! Looking at it now, that last part felt like a 'oh, duh' moment for me. Thank you for the help. But unfortunately, I've still got my main problem, that the counter resets to what it starts at when I refresh the browser page.

Comment: This should work: http://pastebin.com/4LBmDxFJ It now changes the counter immediately, instead of waiting 2.7 seconds after the page loads, and it doesn't reset anymore after a page refresh.

Comment: Wonderful! I can't thank you enough. And, when I get the reputation, I'll get your answer out of the negatives.

Answer (score 1):

You can use server-sent events. Here are the explanations and examples http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Comment: Never come across those before - Neat!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want this counter to be global, and not per-user.
The approach you've shown is not good. It might work if you use AJAX or some other means of storing values, but that's not really necessary. In fact, I think it's a stupid solution.

Since the counter is increasing constantly, you need to find something that's always present and you can calculate the counter value from. I'm talking about *time*, of course.

Figure out at what time your counter would've been at zero. Make that your reference time. Now, every time the page opens, calculate the counter using `(current time - reference time) * increase value`, so since the increase value is `1 / 2.7` (thanks Matthew) the formula is `(current time in seconds - reference time in seconds) / 2.7)` and there you go! That's the value your counter needs to get upon every page load.

This way, your code will update the counter live on the page, while the time calculations I gave will make sure the counter number is correct "behind the curtains" so that when you refresh the page, you'd get the same value as you'd get if you were at the page the whole time. Just make sure you use one time zone and stick to it to avoid having users from different areas having different counter values (slightly different, but still, you don't need that).

**The bottom line**: *Use your code to update the counter live on the page and use what I've shown you to determine the starting value of the counter when the page loads*.

Comment: I believe it would be `... * 1 / 2.7` as it's add 1 every 2.7 seconds.

Comment: @Matthew Thank you, you're right! I was trying to write the answer as quick as possible :) Updated it now.

Comment: I didn't see your answer until I has posted mine. I guess great minds think alike. :D

Answer (score 0):

[`localStorage`](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) allows you to persist data between page loads on a per-computer basis

```
// load the time from what was saved, or if absent, pick 0
var time = localStorage['timer'] || 0;
var el = document.getElementById('counter');

var timerId;

function startCount() {
    timerId = setInterval(function() {
        time = time + 1;
        localStorage['timer'] = time;
        el.textContent = time;
    }, 2700);
}
```

Comment: This will work if you're only worried about the counter being preserved for one user. If you want the counter to be the same across all users, this won't work.

Comment: @skimberk1: `+new Date()`? That ought to be consistent across all users

Comment: @Eric. Run `new Date()` on your local computer/server. Now, log into a server/computer across the globe. Run `new Date()`. Are the results the exact same as of this point in time? If both those servers are not running on the same exact synchronized timezone, they will not be the same.

Comment: @PenguinCoder He'd actually have to carry his computer across the globe to test that with this code. (or at least change the regional settings) :)

Comment: @PenguinCoder: I assumed `+new Date()` gives you seconds since the epoch, which according to wikipedia is the _"number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 **UTC**, Thursday, 1 January 1970"_